# How to solve NXDOMAIN error on my mac?

Tags: macos, unix, macbook-pro, domain

I have a blog and I recently moved to another hosting company.
I have two laptops, a sony vaio and a macbook pro.
I have noticed that I can access my blog only from the sony vaio.
Using terminal on both laptops I get the following results :

### Vaio Terminal

> nslookup blog.myblogname.org

Server : pirelli.router
Address : my router's ip here

DNS request timed out.
  timeout was 2 seconds.
Name : blog.myblogname.org
Address : my blog ip here

### MacBook Pro Terminal

> nslookup blog.myblogname.org

Server : xx.xx.x.xxx (My isp's primary dns server)
Address : xx.xx.x.xxx#53

** server can't find blog.myblogname.org: NXDOMAIN

I have to note here that my macbook pro is connected on the modem-router(pirelli) using an airport express router.
Thank you.

Comment: Today the blog (blog.devcanvas.org) is not accessible from any of the two laptops.

Comment: Now it is accessible again.Why is this happening?Is it an isp problem?

Comment: Another comment I want to make is that when I contact my hosting provider(midphase) they say that they can access the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a hosting provider problem.
I found a page (just-ping.com) that checks your page from many places of the world and here is the sad picture that shows about 50% success only :

[image]